# Как принимать платежи с карт, без посредников и без организации юридического лица?

Tags: интернет-магазин

Есть некий портал который не подходит модерацию для большинства платформ эквайринга.(онлайн платежей). Где-то нужна регистрация юридического лица, другие которые работают только с физ. лицами с жесткой модерацией. Вроде работаю с горем пополам на freecassa. Но есть минусы:

1. Большая комиссия.
2. Глючит оплата, т.е. клиент через раз может оплатить.

Тут я начал думать, как же другие подобные сайты, которым трудно подключить систему оплаты, работают. Подумал о казино. Наткнулся на казино. Зарегистрировался и сделал оплату. И я так понял что у них напрямую как то работает. Или если не напрямую то как узнать с кем они работают? Вообще можно ли как то принимать оплаты, без посредников. Т.е. напрямую от покупателя?

Comment: Думаю вам стоит закрыть вопрос, так как вы спрашиваете о возможности нарушения Федералного законодательства.

Comment: Не факт, что в его стране действует федеральное законодательство.

Напрямую принимать нельзя, кроме варианта "вот мой номер карточки - пополните". Правила потому и жесткие, что бы избежать мошенничества.

Comment: ну как вариант, можете принимать оплату напрямую на ЯД. Я делал такое, там примерно как форма или кнопка на сайт. Там также есть callback функция в настройках яндекс деньги, можешь указать на обработчик ответов, при успешной/неуспешной оплате. На нескольких проектах стоят, где есть трудности подключения онлайн оплат.

Comment: @m.sultan да попробовал, но есть проблема, если человек не авторизован в системе яндекс он просит го зарегестрироваться. т. е. без регистрации нельзя оплатить

Comment: @duddeniska первый раз слышу чтобы яндекс прямо заставлял клиентов ваших регистрироваться перед оплатой. Он советует )), но не вынуждает. Вы можете оплатить с помощью Банковской карты без регистрации в яндексе.

Comment: А гео ваших пользователей worldwide или только, например, снг?

Comment: ttr.casino, я думаю, работает как юрлицо, но только вне РФ `Registrant Organization: Direx NV` (из whois) `Direx N.V., a company registered and established under the laws of Curacao ... Cyprus.` - из поиска. Кипр... оффшоры... Поэтому принимает карты. `Вообще можно ли как то принимать оплаты, без посредников.` - нет, нужен договор с банком. Ну не напрямую же вы с системой Visa и Mastercard будете работать - в таком случае открывайте свой банк. А те ребята сделали через Кипр. Вам в общем-то, нужно в эту сторону копать.

Comment: Для ТС, чтобы платить напрямую. нужно 1) делать офшор, на Кипре(купил фирму с номинальным директором + счет в банке с доступом). например, 2) делаешь мерчант, например у Visa(если потянешь) или другой платежной системы (в свое время мы работали с Epassporte, до его кончины) и все, ты платишь напрямую.

Comment: Правда в этом случае вас ждут другие сложности. а именно, нужно постоянно держать определенный уровень чарджей, иначе мерчант закроют. Далее борьба с кардерами. иначе мерчант закроют. Далее если системе, где вы сделали мерчант, не понравится происхождения денег или увидят подозрительную транзакцию, тогда будет холд, и вам нужно будет этот вопрос тоже разруливать. Потому, берите обычный яндекс, робокассу, или любой эквайринг российский выключите и все.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch сейчас работаю через free-cassa. Платежи идут с Казахстана. И там у них проблема что карточки Казахстана проходят через 3-4 раза оплата. Пробовал подключать яндекс деньги. Классно все работает четко, написал обработчик. Но тут проблема что если покупатель не зарегестрирован и не авторизован в яндексе, то его просят зарегестрироваться в яндексе. Что не целесообразно.

Comment: @duddeniska Ну у Яндекса свои тарканы, напишите в суппорт яндекса может там что прояснят. Просто по закончу, если ты пополняешь яндекс , или платишь яндекс. нужно авторизоваться.

Comment: @duddeniska платежи могут не проходить через free-cassa кстати если например у карты клиента нет такой технологии типа 3d-secure

Comment: При оплате через Я.Кассу не просят регистрацию, вообще. Ввёл номер карты и вперёд. Не понимаю, в чём проблема у автора. (Приём оплаты без посредников - это только наличные. Всё остальное подразумевает посредников в виде банков, систем типа VISA, и т.п. Вы уж определитесь.)

Comment: Не очень понятна пробелема. Вы не хотите оформлять юридическое лицо и не хотите принимать платежи как физическое лицо. Чем торгуете?

Comment: Оплата через телеграм-ботов спасет Вас (К примеру в Украине - есть возможность через бота Приват24(украинский банк) создать и оплатить платеж, либо самому написать)

Answer (score 0):

Как пример - для того что-бы создать свою платежную систему в европе нужно:

1. Быть ЮР лицом
2. Иметь уставной капитал не менее 200 000 €
3. Быть зарегистрированным как банковский предприниматель и иметь лицензию на совершение финансовых операций.
4. Иметь лицезию представителя SEPA.
5. Иметь сертификат сетевой безопасности не менее чем CERT 7
6. Иметь акредитации MIFID, MiFIR, MIFID II

Альтернативный способ :

1. Принимать платежи в биткоинах и на все выше описаное просто забить.